# two email domains into one email client office 365

Tags: email, outlook, office365

I have 2 (3 actually), office 365 accounts for 2 separate companies and to check/respond to emails, I have to continuously sign-in/out of each.

How do I receive both email accounts into one office 365 account?
I need to be able to respond to both with the correct address (so forwarding is out of the question).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Outlook Online with web browser, you can open different Office 365 accounts in separate windows using browser's private browsing mode:

- Internet Explorer: Tools > InPrivate Browsing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
- Firefox: File > New Private Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
- Chrome: Top-right three-dot menu > New incognito window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

If you have Office 2010 or newer installed on your workstation, you can have multiple Exchange accounts in your mail profile, and use them simultaneously. To add an account in to you profile in Outlook: (Just enter the email address, leave other fields empty and type in password when it's asked)

- File > Account Setting > Account Settings > E-mail > Add...